# Querying with ActiveRecord for values inside a JSON attribute using an array of values

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

```
Rails 7
MySQL 8
```

I have a model ***Author***, with an attribute ***book*** set as a JSON.

The book JSON structure:

```
book => {
          'title', 'pages', 'publication_date'}
        }
```

I have an array of titles:

```
titles = ['Tree','Ice','Pulp']
```

I tried:

```
authors = Author.where("book -> '$.title' = ?", titles)
```

But it did not work.

I was trying to model it after what works for a non-JSON attribute:

```
values = [1, 2, 3]
records = Model.where(column_name: values)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: This is the classic scenario that illustrates why json columns (and array columns) are seldom a good idea. I suggest you restructure your db. Book should have columns called title, pages and pub_date.

Comment: That's an answer to the question I asked. A JSON field is a way to create different versions of the data, without having to resort to endless tables, or modifications to the DB schema. The model in question may not be as simple as a single attribute.

Comment: there's always a tradeoff... usually searchability and indexability are important criteria. Hopefully someone will give you the answer you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were so close:

```rb
Author.where("book -> '$.title' IN (?)", titles)
```